# How to set image pattern to an Image in image tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to set image pattern to an Image in image tag.
I have found change image color using below code but I want to draw perticuler patterns(for e.g. Checks, strips, dotted etc) on the image.
I want solution for above concern,
Thanks in advance

```
function colorImage(imgId,hexaColor) {
    // create hidden canvas (using image dimensions)
    var imgElement = document.getElementById(imgId);

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElement.width;
    canvas.height = imgElement.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElement,0,0);

    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    var data = imageData.data;

    // convert image to grayscale
    var rgbColor = hexToRgb(hexaColor);

    for(var p = 0, len = data.length; p < len; p+=4) {
        //if(data[p+3] == 0)
        //   continue;
        data[p + 0] = rgbColor.r;
        data[p + 1] = rgbColor.g;
        data[p + 2] = rgbColor.b;
        //data[p + 3] = 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // replace image source with canvas data
    imgElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Comment: You can either draw a shape upon your current image xy, and also put an image on top of the image. Is that the direction you are looking for?

Comment: what about [`ctx.createPattern()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern) ? Did you search for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to modify loop which does the drawing, for example this should produce some stripes:

```
for(var p = 0, len = data.length; p < len; p+=4) {
    if ( (p % 8) == 0 ) {
       data[p + 0] = 0;
       data[p + 1] = 0;
       data[p + 2] = 0;
    } else {
       data[p + 0] = 255;
       data[p + 1] = 255;
       data[p + 2] = 255;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to get images with part of pattern and tile them like this:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable  = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile_image));
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: It seems you are answering an Android question while this one is tagged javascript. [tag:canvas] is a mess...